# Ubuntu 18.04 suddenly not starting anymore

Tags: 18.04, startup, freeze, error-handling

The system worked fine yesterday - but after starting it up again this morning, it just decided to fail on me. Endless loading screen, before it suddenly switches to a console view to show me this:

Everything is [ OK ], but the last two messages are:

```
[ 33.212602 ] usb 1-1: device not accepting address 3, error -101y server...p link was shut down...
[ 33.213252 ] usb 2-1: device not accepting address 3, error -110
```

I disconnected ALL USB devices (only a keyboard was attached). No change.

When trying to check /var/log/syslog, I read stuff like:

```
"Critical unable to create DBUS proxy for gnomeserver"
```

I tried switching to lightDM, no effect (I reach a login screen, but it freezes after a successful login just showing the background image and no GUI).

I went through about 30 threads with similar mentioned problems, I updated / upgraded all packages, removed `gnome-screensaver`, rebooted with older versions - nothing.

Any ideas? I can't find anything to try anymore - and I'm afraid to break it further.

The installation is only about half a year old, and besides using NGINX and php7.2, it is pretty vanilla. No major packages or alterations.

**Edit 1:**

`dmesg`

```
usb1-1: device not accepting address 2, error -110
usb2-1: device not accepting address 2, error -110
usb2-1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
usb1-1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
random: crng init done
usb1-1: device not accepting address 3, error -110
usb2-1: device not accepting address 3, error -110
usb usb2-port1: attempt power cycle
usb usb1-port1: attempt power cycle
usb2-1: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
usb1-1: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
usb1-1: device not accepting address 4, error -110
usb2-1: device not accepting address 4, error -110
usb2-1: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
usb1-1: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
```

`lsusb` and `lsusb -t`

[image]

Comment: Did you try the suggestions given here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-session/+bug/1728383 i.e. removing `gnome-sessions` as well as dodgy gnome-extensions?

Comment: @Jos yes, no change at all, sadly. I didn't even have any gnome-extensions installed.

Comment: Are there any other USB-related errors mentioned in `dmesg`?

Comment: @Jos added the output in my Question - and: the only USB device attached is the keyboard, which works fine. I do not (and never did, so far) use any other USB-Slots so far.

Comment: Try `lsusb` or `lsusb -t` to find out which USB slot is giving hardware problems.

Comment: @Jos added a picture of the outputs, since I can't really copy them

Comment: Does your keyboard work on all of the USB ports?

Comment: @Jos yes it works on all (the machine has 10 port). And without any noticable delay when switching port.